# Loading Data - Skip first line & Columns Don't match

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a data set into a table and need to skip the first line of that csv file and also need to leave the first column blank for an id auto increment to fill it.

Here is what I am trying right now

```
load data local infile 'C:\\bla\blah\file.txt' into table sources_1
fields terminated by '\","'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4) set name=@col1,address@col2,city@col3,state@col4
ignore 1 lines
```

Comment: You're missing a bunch of `=` signs.

Comment: Why are you setting them into temporary variables? And you're omitting quite a lot of `=`'s there.. But `(name,address,city,state)` would work even better then `(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4) set name=@col1,address=@col2,city=@col3,state=@col4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
load data local infile 'C:\\bla\blah\file.txt' into table sources_1
fields terminated by ','
       optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines
(name, address, city, state)
```

It puts the data from the CSV directly into the appropriate columns, no user-variables are needed. Omitting the ID column will cause it to be filled in with the auto-increment value.

The `IGNORE 1 LINES` clause should be before the column names.

Comment: Ahhh you are awesome this worked perfectly. One more question - When it input the data the first column 'name' had quotes at the beginning of each entry. Do you know how I would get ride of this?

Comment: See the changes I made to the `fields` clause.